# React Native/Javascript - How to know that object does not have the property?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Let say :

```
myVariable.color;
myVariable.height;
myVariable.width;
```

But sometimes, myVariable only have "color" and "height" property.

I have try this, but no luck :

```
if(myVariable.width == undefined) {
//but not filtered here
}
```

How to know if myVariable doesn't contain "width" property by code, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to double negate:

```
if(!!myVariable.width){
    //do something here
}
```

Comment: Nope, not the answer.

Comment: @IsaacCarolWeisberg I know about `hasOwnProperty` but .. what's wrong with above code? Why isn't it the answer .. It does not do what it should do?

Comment: The thing is that you could've assigned `undefined` to the `width` yourself, or alternatively you could have never assigned to `width` anything in the first place. But: if you have never touched the property setter, then `hasOwnProperty` and `in` will return false. However, if you assign `undefined` to `width` manually, your check will still fail since the value is `undefined`, but `hasOwnProperty` and `in` will be both true because this key was actually set.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `hasOwnProperty`.

If you would like to perform a search in the whole potential prototype chain of an object, you can also use the `in` operator.

```
if (width in object) {
```

Comment: Is it secure if implement in React Native ?

Comment: Yes, this is a feature of JS runtime and not the browser/node specifically.